# Fatal error: uncaught exception without try/catch block

Tags: php, exception, uncaught-exception

I'm trying to throw an exception when a form field is empty and also when an insert query is unsuccessful. I've seen someone throw exceptions before without using try/catch blocks and without including an Exceptions class. Does anyone know how I would go about doing so?

This is the error I am getting when I do not fill in all fields:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Error: The following fields are empty- Title, Phone Number, Email, ' in /vagrant/web/Assignment4/Person.php on line 94 Exception: Error: The following fields are empty- Title, Phone Number, Email, in /vagrant/web/Assignment4/Person.php on line 94 Call Stack: 0.0014 638168 1. {main}() /vagrant/web/Assignment4/Form.php:0 0.0172 698568 2. Person->insert() /vagrant/web/Assignment4/Form.php:179

```
public function insert()
{

  //Storing required $_POST array fields in variable for isset function    
   $errorArray = array();   

   $expectedValues = array(
       "firstName"   => "First Name",
       "lastName"    => "Last Name",
       "title"       => "Title",
       "office"      => "Office",
       "phoneNumber" => "Phone Number",
       "email"       => "Email",
       );


   //Checking to see if all fields are filled in 

    foreach ($expectedValues as $field => $humanName) { 
       if (empty($_POST[$field])) { 
        $errorArray[] = $humanName . ", ";
       }
    }   

    if (count($errorArray) > 0) {
           throw new Exception("Error: The following fields are empty- " .implode(' ', $errorArray));
         }


    else{


       //If they are, insert them into the Perosn table    

               $insert = $this-> doQuery("INSERT INTO Person 
                                         VALUES(
                                        '$_POST[firstName]',
                                        '$_POST[lastName]',
                                        '$_POST[title]',
                                        '$_POST[office]',
                                        '$_POST[phoneNumber]',
                                        '$_POST[email]')");



         //If insert query is successful, return true 
            if ($insert === true){
                echo "<h2>" . "Congragulations! You now work for Assignment 4 Incorporated" . "</h2>";
                return true;
            }


         //If not, throw an exception    

          /*  else{
                throw new Exception
                ("<p>" . "Error: Query was unsuccessful:" . " " . $this->error . "</p>");
               }

               try{
                   $insert == true;
               }
               catch (Exception $x){
                   echo $x->getMessage;
               }      
   */
        }

   }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can't throw a catch error without "trying" something;

```
$errorArray = array();   

$expectedValues = array(
    "firstName"   => "First Name",
    "lastName"    => "Last Name",
    "title"       => "Title",
    "office"      => "Office",
    "phoneNumber" => "Phone Number",
    "email"       => "Email",
);

try{
    foreach ($expectedValues as $field => $humanName) { 
        if (empty($_POST[$field])) { 
            $errorArray[] = $humanName . ", ";
        }
    }   

    if (count($errorArray) > 0) {
        throw new Exception("Error: The following fields are empty- " .implode(' ', $errorArray));
    }else{
        $insert = $this-> doQuery("INSERT INTO Person 
            VALUES(
            '$_POST[firstName]',
            '$_POST[lastName]',
            '$_POST[title]',
            '$_POST[office]',
            '$_POST[phoneNumber]',
            '$_POST[email]')"
        );

        if ($insert === true){
            echo "<h2>" . "Congragulations! You now work for Assignment 4 Incorporated" . "</h2>";
            return true;
        }
    }
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();  
}
```

in your code, you threw an error before ever trying, hince the fatal error "uncaught exception without try/catch block". the code caught an error but it wasn't really trying to catch anything.

Comment: Ahh, extremely helpful. My eyes have been opened. Thank you, Sir!